# how do you store multiple rows and column array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have an array of checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]"  value="move" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]"  value="move2" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]"  value="move3" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]"  value="move4" />
```

Depending on the number of checkboxes selected, a table with corresponding number of rows is generated.

```
for($x=0; $x<$N; $x++)
{
    echo nl2br("<td><textarea name=art[] rows=10 cols=30></textarea>   </td><td><textarea name=science[] rows=10 cols=30></textarea></td></textarea></td><td><textarea name=method[] rows=10 cols=30></textarea></td><td><textarea name=criteria[] rows=10 cols=30></textarea></td></tr>"); 
}
```

I cannot tell how many table rows with corresponding columns will be generated each time. So how to write the code to insert each set of row array is a problem. I have tried the

```
$optionsVal = implode(",", $data);
```

but that only works to store the selected options and not for the generated table rows and columns.Please can anyone help with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get it. Can you try to explain your problem with other words?

Comment: Implode is used to join array elements with a string...how is that relevant to your question of storage of multiple rows and columns in an array...that's in fact, what an array is...

Comment: Normalize the database

Comment: @hek2mgl for every selected checkbox, a table row is generated. i want to store the the content in the generated rows and columns in the db. i want to know how write the code and query

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I think I understand a little better, but perhaps you should relay your question in other terms.

Basically my understanding is that you are accepting an uncertain (within the boundaries of the number of checkboxes you have) number of checkboxes, which there in turn generate a row for each selected check box.

If you want to store these generated rows in mySQL you need to post the data back to the database

```
$result = mysqli_query($query, $conn);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

You need to set a $result similar to this, and store your check box values in it
In this example if the end-user hits the save button it inserts the values from the check box into a variable

```
if(isset($_POST["savebtn"]))
{
    //inserting the new information
    $id = $_POST[""];
    $name = $_POST[""]; 



    //iterate through each checkbox selected

foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $loc_id)
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO table(ID, Loc_Code) VALUES('$id', '$loc_id')";
  $result = mysqli_query($query, $conn);
}


?>
```

This was just kinda taken from another example, but you are way off with the implode, you need to save the results of the php selection to variables first, and then assign them rows in mySQL by looping through the selection

UPDATE:

Okay, so you got them in an array, seelction[] - this is good now you would want to check to see if a certain value is selected...

```
if (in_array("move2", $_POST['selection'])) { /* move2 was selected */}
```

then you want to put that into a single string - you were right with the implode method

```
echo implode("\n", $_POST['selection']);
```

then echo it out with a foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST['selection'] as $selection) {
     echo "You selected: $selection <br>";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the checkboxes are inserting into a table (options). but this does not insert the content of the generated rows. pls could you clarify some more? t

Comment: it gives me an error of "column count does not match value count at row 1 " when i try to use this method to insert the generated table

Comment: start small - i updated answer to steps - you want to make sure your sql insert statement matches the column count with appropriate values otherwise it will bomb out with the column count does not match error

Comment: that's a sql error and you can google the error, it is rather simple to fix